# PHP mail () function withan attachment not working

Tags: php, html

Php mail() function with a attachment(resume) is not working,i used below code but its showing error saying sending mail failed,i dont understand what the problem is.I tried some other methods too but they all showing same "mail faied" error,Below is my code,

```
   $config['upload_path'] = dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]) . "/assets/backend/uploads";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|doc|docx';
         $this->load->library('upload',$config);
         if($this->upload->do_upload('images'))
        {
           $filedata = $this->upload->data();
            $filename = $filedata["raw_name"].$filedata["file_ext"];

        }

$to = 'testname@gmail.com'; 

$subject = 'Test email with attachment'; 

$random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 

$headers = "From: hxxxxx6@gmail.com\r\nReply-To: hxxxxx6@gmail.com.com"; 

$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 

$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents(base_url().'assets/backend/uploads/'.$filename))); 

ob_start(); 
?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>" 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!! 
This is simple text email message. 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Hello World!</h2> 
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p> 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="base_url().'assets/backend/uploads/'.$filename"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment  

<?php echo $attachment; ?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

<?php 

$message = ob_get_clean(); 

$mail_sent = mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
"Mail failed" 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
```

Comment: what its showing

Comment: This article on how to attach files with mail() might be of some assistance - https://www.codexworld.com/send-email-with-attachment-php/

Comment: @KumarPraveen its showing "Mail Failed" when i click submit button

Comment: @jeff i tried that code too but didn't work let me try again'

Comment: It looks like you're using codeigniter? In that case, why not use [their email class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html?highlight=email) instead?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes Im using codeignter

Comment: So why not use their mail class instead? Then you won't need to manually build the mail body.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson its giving me this error  strpos(): Empty needle

Comment: @MagnusEriksson



    `$from_email = "h*****76@gmail.com"; 
         $to_email ="*****76@gmail.com"; 
   
         //Load email library 
         $this->load->library('email'); 
   
         $this->email->from($from_email, 'Your Name'); 
         $this->email->to($to_email);
         $this->email->subject('Email Test'); 
         $this->email->message($htmlContent); 

         if($this->email->send()) 
         {
            echo "<h1>send</h1>";
         }`